# Postgres query json array to find the count which matches the condition

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, postgresql-12

I have a table `my_table` with a column name `itinerary` in my Postgres 12 DB.

```
 select column_name, data_type from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'my_table' and column_name = 'itinerary';
 column_name | data_type
-------------+-----------
 itinerary   | ARRAY
(1 row)
```

Every element in the itinerary is a JSON with the field name `address`, which has the field name `city`. I can find the count which matches the condition for the first element of the `itinerary` by using the following query:

```
select count(*) from my_table where lower(itinerary[1]->'address'->>'city') = 'oakland';
count
-------
    12
(1 row)
```

and I can also find the length of an array by using the following query:

```
select array_length(itinerary, 1) from my_table limit 1;
```

I would like to find all the records which can have a city name `Oakland` in their itinerary, not only as a first stop. I am not sure how to figure out that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `exists` and `unnest()`:

```
select count(*)
from mytable t
where exists (
    select 1
    from unnest(t.itinerary) as x(obj)
    where x.obj -> 'address'->>'city' = 'oakland'
)
```

Comment: works like a charm. Thank you. I was unaware of the unnest function. Ref: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-array.html.